You are not authorized to perform this operation (LambdaEC2SnapshotRole)
I'm a new bee to AWS and trying to create a EBS snapshot using lambda function but facing a permission error.
Error:
> Error Creating Snapshot An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when
> calling the CreateSnapshot operation: You are not authorized to
> perform this operation. User:
> arn:aws:sts::Account-id:assumed-role/LambdaEC2SnapshotRole/lambdaEc2Snapshot
> is not authorized to perform: ec2:CreateTags on resource:
> arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::snapshot/* because no identity-based policy
> allows the ec2:CreateTags action.

after going through some blogs and this
AWS policy for creating only the snapshots, i have created below policy for lambda and still facing same error. can you please advice on what could be the issue.
Code
import json
import boto3
import logging
from datetime import datetime

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
BASE = pathlib.Path().resolve()
lambda_client = boto3.client("lambda")



def handler(event, context):
    myec2 = boto3.client("ec2")
    current_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    print("Hey hello")
    try:
        response = myec2.create_snapshot(
            Description = "My Ec2 Daily Snapshot",
            VolumeId = "vol-0ce1640002f882ad1",
            TagSpecifications = [
                {
                    "ResourceType": "snapshot",
                    "Tags": [
                        {
                        
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": f"My Ec2 Snapshot {current_date}"
                        
                        }
                        
                    ]

                }
            ]
        )
        logger.info(f" Successfully Created Snapshot {json.dumps(response, default=str)}")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error Creating Snapshot {str(e)}")
    

Policy that I've set
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumes"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}


And the mentioned missing ec2:CreateTags to the permission policy.

here is my updated policy {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
"ec2:CreateSnapshot",
"ec2:DescribeInstances",
"ec2:DescribeVolumes"
],
"Resource": ""
},
{
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
"ec2:CreateTags"
],
"Resource": ""
}
]
}

thanks to luk2302 for pointing out the issue, ec2:CreateTags was missing in my policy statement below is my updated policy
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumes"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

below document is helpful too..
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/supported-iam-actions-tagging.html

You could just add ec2:CreateTags to the existing Action list; no need to create a separate statement for it.

Thanks deceze, I have update the statement now
